# Add Cartoview apps to an existing GeoNode installation

Tags: geonode

I´m using GeoNode 2.6.3, running on ubuntu server 16.04. I´ve seen some [Cartoview apps](http://appstore.cartoview.net/?page=4) that might be usefull for our porpouse, but i´m not sure if [this instructions](https://cartologic.github.io/installation_ubuntu/) work on a GeoNode instance that is alredy running. It instructs to install (again) postgresql, geoserver, and other that GeoNode is alredy using.

- Will it work if i skip the first steps and configure the new databases on the existing Postgresql 9.5?
- If I install cartoview, is it safe for all exsisting data (layers, maps, users, groups) to keep working fine?

If any has done so, please confirm that it works well. I just don´t want to start the instalation and mess up what is alredy working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it will work, just install cartoview 1.4.4 which is compatible with geonode 2.6.3.
cartoview is an extension for geonode and don't play with geonode models at all.

```
pip install cartoview==1.4.4
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

N.B:using latest version of cartoview 1.8 will not work as it is compatible with geonode 2.8.